# How does Windows 8 appear on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, windows

I'm trying to figure out how many Windows 8 users are using my website. On Google Analytics, I don't explicitly see the number 8 anywhere in the top 10 Windows operating system versions. I don't believe that Windows 8 percentage is so low that it doesn't even show up. It must be miscategorized under another name. Which one is it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it might be [NT 6.2](http://windows8os.com/help/google-analytics-doesnt-display-windows-8-os-in-audience/) until google fixes this.